# Angularjs factory inject error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory, angularjs-injector

I'm using `angularJS` and when I'm injecting a Factory I get error:

**app.js :**

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
```

**myfactory.js :**

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
.factory('httpService', function($http, $timeout) {

});
```

Controller: **test.js :**

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
.controller('test',  function($scope, $timeout, $sce, $http, httpService) {

  $scope.submit = function() {
  }
});
```

When I add `httpService` I get error. Everything seems to be right, I even use this factory in all projects. **Error:**

```
angular.min.js:92 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/unpr?p0=httpServiceProvider%20%3C-%20httpService
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:81/chah/assets/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:6:450
at http://localhost:81/chah/assets/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:36:202
at Object.c [as get] (http://localhost:81/chah/assets/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:34:305)
at http://localhost:81/chah/assets/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:36:270
at c (http://localhost:81/chah/assets/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:34:305)
at d (http://localhost:81/chah/assets/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:35:6)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:81/chah/assets/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:35:165)
at http://localhost:81/chah/assets/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:67:419
at http://localhost:81/chah/assets/js/angularjs/angular.min.js:54:25
```

Comment: which version of Angular your using ?.

Comment: @shushanthp I tested in both angular 1.2.25 and 1.3.9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the link in your error (https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=httpServiceProvider%20%3C-%20httpService):

You create module multiple times:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
```

You should do it once. Then use without []

```
angular.module('myapp').factory ...
angular.module('myapp').controller ...
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the error is because in the creation of the `httpService` and the `controller` you have used the `setter` i.e. `angular.module('myapp', [])` syntax for the `module` and not the `getter`  syntax. `angular.module('myapp')`.
Angular requires us to define a module only once, thus the subsequent redefining causes the error.

So in `app.js`, define the `module`:

```
angular.module('myapp', []) ;
```

In `myfactory.js` use the getter Syntax by removing the `, []`:

```
angular.module('myapp')
.factory('httpService', function($http, $timeout) {
});
```

And in `test.js`:

```
angular.module('myapp')
.controller('test',  function($scope, $timeout, $sce, $http,  httpService) {

$scope.submit = function() {
}
});
```

Here is a link to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr)

Answer (score 1):

yes,

what you are doing is re-creating your app

what you need to do is define it once and continue using that instance

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.factory('httpService', function($http, $timeout) {

});

app.controller('test',  function($scope, $timeout, $sce, $http, httpService) {

  $scope.submit = function() {
  }
});
```

or if you want to retrieve your app the syntax is angular.module('myapp')
this returns 'myapp', but adding [], tells angular to create an app and not fetch it

Comment: There are different js files as mentioned in the question properly,

Comment: doesnt matter... you can define window.app = ... and then continue using that variable, or as i state you can use angular.module('myapp') to fetch your app, but the proper way, or at least how i like to do it, is to continue using that variable

Comment: window is global thing , if its not used with IIFE

Comment: @shushanthp - so what? Doesn't matter as long as the separate files are loaded n the right order.

Comment: yes It doesn't matter , But The syntax used in the question also works you don't have to cache with a variable as far modularity of the appliaction is concerened

Comment: @shushanthp - not sure what your point is, but, the syntax in the question does not work, it is using the module setter multiple times.

Comment: the syntax would work if you would remove the '[]' parameter, but as far as good practice you should define a variable an then load your files in the right order

Comment: do not define a 'app' variable, it is a bad pratice. instead use `angular.module('myapp', []) ;` to define a new module and `angular.module('myapp').` to use it the other files or code. see @Evans Dianga answer please

Comment: I meant its bad practice to use app variable , the question has properly used it angular module in different files , no need to use app variable .

Answer (score 0):

Code should look like below:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
.factory('httpService', function($http, $timeout) {

});
.controller('test',  function($scope, $timeout, $sce, $http, httpService) {

  $scope.submit = function() {
  }
});
```